# Django Migrate - row has an invalid foreign key but row does not exist

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-admin

When migrating my database, I get the following error:

```
The row in table 'project_obicase' with primary key '2325' has an invalid foreign key: project_obicase.ckId_id contains a value '2443' that does not have a corresponding value in project_pupiladdressck.id.
```

Looking in my /admin/ site i cannot find this record '2325'. It skips from 2324 to 2333

project_obicase table:

[image]

Is there any way to resolve this foreign key mishap if I cannot locate the object? I'd be happy to remove record 2325 if I can find it.

Thanks

Comment: show all the models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by deleting the records manually from the DB shell. (as the records did not appear on the front end)

> manage.py dbshell

```
delete from table
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM other_table t WHERE table.id = other_table.foreign_key)
```